# how to call java code from another java code using functions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing a project on predicting student performance..for that I have to  read a datasets from excel sheet using eclipse I have completed reading the datasets..now from this java code i have to call another code where we use MultiLayer perceptron algorithm for predicting..can I know how to call another code i.e MLP code using functions

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class Dataset1 {
    public static void main( String [] args ) { 
        try { 
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream("D:\\sampledoc.xls")); 
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input ); 
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs); 
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 

            while( rows.hasNext() ) 
            {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator(); 
                while( cells.hasNext() ) 
                { 
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next(); 
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) 
                        System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+" " );
                    else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) 
                        System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+" " ); 
                    else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) 
                        System.out.print( cell.getBoolean CellValue()+" " ); 
                    else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType()) 
                        System.out.print( "BLANK " ); 
                    else System.out.print("Unknown cell type"); 
                } 
            } 
        } catch( IOException ex ) { 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

this is the code I am using to read the datasets and i got result successfully...now how to call another java program in this code using functions

Comment: what did you mean by `another java program` and `another  java code`? 
Do you want to call the methods in another java class?

Comment: I'm so confused.  You're already calling other code using functions all over the place.  Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your project as a `.jar` file and add that jar in another project dependencies.

In eclipse, you export a project as a jar: 
`right mouse click on project -> Export -> Java...Jar file`

In another project you add jar dependency:
`right mouse click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add Jars...` and add your jar there.

In the project itself, use the names of the classes you need, just like your'e used to.

Of cause, if you want to use some "function" `bar()` from your project, that's written in some class `Foo`, which is in the `jar` you've created, you need to instantiate the class `Foo` (if the "function" is not static) if it's static, use `Foo.bar()`. But that's basic java...